# Customer can't register an account during order process,redirect to the shopping cart page

Tags: magento-1.9

Everyone thought it was an old one.Actually, it is.magento 1.9.1.0,When I checked out, clicking on my account was redirected back to the shopping cart page.It's not just this version, I've installed 1.9.x and most of them will.But I looked for a lot and still couldn't find a solution.Any friends know, please help me, thank you very much!